# About double integral convergence

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals

Does the below integral converge?

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{|x|<n} \int_{|y|<n}\sin\left(x^2+y^2\right)\,dx\,dy$$

I saw this on the multiple choice test. The choices were

$$0 \\ \pi\\ -\pi\\ \text{does not converge}$$

I am sorry to ask this question, but I got stuck on this. Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Answer (score 5):

\begin{align}
&\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_{-n}^n{\int_{-n}^n{\sin \left( x^2+y^2 \right) \text{d}x\text{d}y}}\\&=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_{-n}^n{\int_{-n}^n{\left[ \sin x^2\cos y^2+\sin y^2\cos x^2 \right] \text{d}x\text{d}y}}\\
&=2\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_{-n}^n{\int_{-n}^n{\left[ \sin x^2\cos y^2 \right] \text{d}x\text{d}y}}\\
&=2\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_{-n}^n{\sin x^2\text{d}x}\int_{-n}^n{\cos y^2\text{d}y}\\
&=2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\sin x^2\text{d}x}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\cos y^2\text{d}y}\\
&=2\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}=\pi 
\end{align}

Comment: How did you get from the second to the third line?

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor you can change x to y and y to x in the second part of the integral. They are just two symbols

Comment: @CHRIS They are just two “dummy variables” : )

Comment: @CHRIS Why can you just flip the variables in part of the argument but not the rest? Have you seen a proof of this somewhere?

Comment: If you take the statement $$\sin(x^2)\cos(y^2)+\sin(y^2)\cos(x^2)=2\sin(x^2)\cos(y^2)$$ it is false for many values, including $(x,y)=(3,1)$.

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor $$\int_{-n}^n\int_{-n}^n f(x,y)+f(y,x) \,dx\,dy=\int_{-n}^n\int_{-n}^n f(y,x) \,dx\,dy+\int_{-n}^n\int_{-n}^n f(x,y) \,dx\,dy$$. They are symmetrical.

Comment: @WongAustin Thank you; that makes sense.

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor If you can't understand that, consider this substitution :u=x, v=y. Then use x=v, y=u. This method is universally used in calculating integrals